# ResNet50 base model for multi-label classification predicting only label

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I am using a ResNet50 as base model to predict multiple label in an image and sum up the respective values of the labels.

reading the data:

```
#read the data
data_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Notifyer-dataset/dataset'

def load_dataset(folder):
    X = []  # create an empty list to store the images
    y = []  # create an empty list to store the labels

    # get a list of all the files in the folder
    filenames = os.listdir(folder)

    # iterate over the files
    for filename in filenames:
        # get the label from the filename
        label = filename.split('_')[0]
        # open the image file and convert it to a NumPy array
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(folder, filename))
        image = image.resize((200, 200))  # resize the image to 200x200
        image = image.convert('RGB')  # convert the image to RGB
        image = np.array(image) / 255  # normalize the pixel values
        image = image.reshape(-1, 200, 200, 3)  # reshape to (batch_size, height, width, channels)
        # append the image and label to the list
        X.append(image)
        y.append(label)
        
    # convert the lists to NumPy arrays
    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)
    #preprocessing
    X = X.reshape(-1, 200, 200, 3)  # reshape arrays to 200x200 images with 1 channel
    X = X / 255.0  # normalize pixel values
    #one hot encoding
    num_classes = len(np.unique(y))
    y = to_categorical(y, num_classes)

    
    return X, y,num_classes

X, y, num_classes = load_dataset(data_path)
```

building the model:

```
def build_r_cnn_model(num_classes):
    """
    Build a region-based CNN model.
    
    Parameters:
    num_classes (int): number of classes to classify
    
    Returns:
    Model: the R-CNN model
    """
    # load the ResNet50 model pre-trained on ImageNet
    base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(200, 200, 3))
    
    # freeze the base model layers
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    
    # add a global average pooling layer
    x = base_model.output
    x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

    # add a fully-connected layer
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)

    # add a dropout layer
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

    # add a classification layer
    predictions = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

    #build the model
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
    return model
```

compiling the model:

```
# build and compile the model
model = build_r_cnn_model(num_classes)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

training the model:

```
#train
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=128, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

function to sum up all label values in the image:

```
#function to calculate total sum of value of predicted labels
def predict_total_sum(model, image):
    y_pred = model.predict(image)  # classify the image
    
    # define a lookup table to map class indices to values
    value_lookup = {
        0: 1, # class 0 corresponds to value 1
        1: 2,  # class 1 corresponds to value 2
    }
    
    total_sum = 0
    for prediction in y_pred:
        # get the class index with the highest predicted probability
        class_index = np.argmax(prediction)
        print(class_index)
        # add the value of the detected denomination to the total sum
        total_sum += value_lookup[class_index]
        
    return total_sum
```

It gives value 1 or 2 for every image for each model compilation which means it is only predicting only one label even if the image has multiple objects of both the labels.

My dataset is small and every image in it contains object of one of the label, do I need to diversify my dataset to make the model identify both labels in an image or is there something wrong with the model architecture? I have also tried to build a CNN model from scratch but it is giving the same result...

Answer (score 0):

I think the output of model.predict has shape [1, num_of_classes] (you can verify it by printing it's shape once). Hence when you are looping on y_pred then you basically iterate only once and add one of the class index to the total_sum. Even if the shape was [num_of_classes], then also I think that this is not how you should try multi-class classification. Would prefer you to read more about how multiclass classification is done.
You can take help from this link: https://www.kaggle.com/code/prateek0x/multiclass-image-classification-using-keras

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand that the output of model.predict has shape [1, num_of_classes] and that this is not how multi-class classification is typically done, I'm trying more for multi-label classification. Could you provide some guidance on how I can modify my model or approach to be able to predict multiple labels and even the count of these labels in the image? The kaggle notebook being a multi-class classification also outputs the same shape.